# How to linearize a pde system in a solution $u_0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have 
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+\mu u+\lvert u\rvert^2u,~~u=u(x,t).
$$

We can write this as the coupled system
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+\mu u+\bar{u}u^2\\
\bar{u_t}=\bar{u_{xx}}+\mu\bar{u}+u\bar{u}^2.
$$

Now, suppose we have a solution $u_0=r\cdot e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$, where $k,\omega,r$ are constants.

My question is: How can we linearize the coupled system in $u_0$?

The result is claimed to be
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+\mu u+2u_0\bar{u_0}u+u_0^2\bar{u}\\
\bar{u_t}=\bar{u_{xx}}+\mu\bar{u}+2\bar{u_0}u_0\bar{u}+\bar{u_0}^2u
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the first of the equations and set $\bar{u}=\bar{u}_0+\epsilon \bar{u}_1$ so we ignore higher order terms of size $\epsilon^2$.

Also $u=u_0+\epsilon u_1$ then substitute these two expansions into the equation. Collect the terms of order$\epsilon$ and  you will have the desired equation